# How does RPM determine the permissions of the installed package?

Tags: permissions, rpm

If you explicitly state -,root,root in the %defattr then the installed packaged will belong to root - root, and will have 'default' permissions (due to the -. Replacing it with a three-digit octal give the installed files those permissions instead of 'default permissions').

I am wondering how RPM determines what permissions to give when using '-'? I think it is related to umask, but I'm currently testing to confirm. If it is related to umask, then when exactly does the umask get applied?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

umask removes permissions from the defaults of 0666 for files.  If you have a umask of 0022, then you end up with effective default permissions on new files/folders of 0644.  You can see the default umask that your account has with the umask command and no parameters.  It is normally set at login time by the /etc/bashrc file and /etc/profile file.

Comment: Let's say you wanted 0777 for files, how would you set your umask for this? I'm not going to actually do this, I'm just curious.